# Timer won't reset to 30 mins - everytime I go back to this page,the timer still is runnng

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone knows how to fix this?My Timer won't reset to 30mins whenever I go back to the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734366/does-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-thismy-timer-wont-reset-to-30mins-whenever-i-go-b)

Here's my code i hope someone can help me,thank you

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
        if (Session["CountdownTimer"] == null )
        {
            Session["CountdownTimer"] = new CountDownTimer(TimeSpan.Parse("00:30:00"));
            (Session["CountdownTimer"] as CountDownTimer).Start();
        }
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["CountdownTimer"] != null)
    {
        if (Label1.Text != "00:00:00")
        {
            Label1.Text = (Session["CountdownTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.ToString();
            Session["time"] = Label1.Text;
        }
        else if((Session["CountdownTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.Seconds <= 0)
        {
            (Session["CountdownTimer"] as CountDownTimer).Stop();
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Response.Redirect("timer.aspx");
        }
    }
}

public class CountDownTimer
{
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft;
    System.Threading.Thread thread;
    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan original)
    {
        this.TimeLeft = original;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        // Start a background thread to count down time
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01"));

            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Start a background thread to count down time
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                TimeLeft = (TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"));

            }
        });
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Alvin, welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a little hard to answer right now. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to get some guidance on writing good questions which are most likely to get answers. The code you've got here is a great start, but what we really need to know is what you're trying to do. Edit your question and add that information, then you should see some more helpful answers.

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact same question yesterday or the day before?

Comment: Yes. You did, and it was closed as not a question. Maybe next time consider rephrasing instead of copy/paste. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734366/does-anyone-knows-how-to-fix-thismy-timer-wont-reset-to-30mins-whenever-i-go-b

Comment: Voting to close as exact duplicate of previous incarnation of the copy/pasted question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve.  Some observations, however, might help you get what you need?

- `Timer1_Tick` is never being called.
- `CountDownTimer.Start` has a `while(true)` loop that never exits.
- `CountDownTimer.Start` doesn't do anything interesting after the sleep
- `CountDownTimer.Stop` also has a while(true)` loop that never exits.
- What does `Timer1.Enable` do?
- What are you trying to do here?  That is completely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answer... but does not fit in comment...

In most cases to implement any sort of timer one can rely on existing time (DateTime.Now) and knowing when timer start/stops.

It may be good idea to rethink your design. Following things lead to strange/unexpected behaviors:

- putting non-serializable objects in session state,
- relying on in memory session state to be be persistent (i.e. survive application rebuilds, server restarts)
- using threads in ASP.Net application
- using Thread.Abort
- using Thread.Sleep

Comment: +1  I was thinking the same thing... but I needed to get past the code/intent first.

Comment: OP was told this two days ago and he just copy/pasted his problem into a new question.